# Hat accent on bold greek letters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, accents, greek

I would like to insert an **hat accent** on **bold letters/symbols** in **math mode**.

For latin letters, e.g. the `q` char, I insert this commands in my preamble

```
\newcommand{\paramhat}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\param}[1]{\textbf{\text{#1}}}
```

And then `\param{q}` and `\paramhat{q}` in the text and everything work as expected.

But the question is: how to make this to work with **greek letters/symbols**?

I need to use it on a `\theta` symbol. I've tried `$\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$` but I think that the hat accent has slightly shifted to the right, as shown in the following image.

[image: bold theta with hat accent]

There is a way to move the hat accent slightly to the left?

---

*Notes:*

- `amsmath` package loaded
- `euler` font for math
- `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
- `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plain TeX, and LaTeX, have a `\skew` macro which is described in the TeXBook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Normal: & a$\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$b \\
\textbackslash skew-.5:   & a$\boldsymbol{\skew{-.5}\hat\theta}$b \\
\textbackslash skew-1:   & a$\boldsymbol{\skew{-1}\hat\theta}$b \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: skew hat]

with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` the hat moves: it is lowered and shifted a bit to the left of its non-T1 position.

[image: skew bis]

Answer (score 4):

This also works great for moving the hat in beamer when the math mode font is italicized.  For my quantum mechanics work, I define:

\newcommand{\op}[1]{\skew{4}\hat{#1}}

Which puts the hats in the right place, not too far to the left, with the new command \op{H}.  YMMV.

[image: Hamiltonians: normal hat and shifted hat]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look shifted to me, but you can use `\hskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Normal: & a$\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$b \\
.1pt:   & a$\hskip-.1pt\boldsymbol{\hat{\hskip.1pt\theta}}$b \\
1mm:    & a$\hskip-1mm\boldsymbol{\hat{\hskip1mm\theta}}$b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For me, this produces the following output:
[image: The example output]

Comment: note that the original question asks about theta using the euler font, in which the greek is upright.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's the same principle, but you're right. I've edited the answer.